# Grid view index changing with filters

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I got this simple gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewFoundations" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  
          Width="100%" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" PageSize="15" 
          CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
          onpageindexchanging="GridViewFoundations_PageIndexChanging">
      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
  <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Id">
  <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lb_id" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "nodeId") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Foundation Name">
  <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lb_foundationName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "text") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastUpdate">
  <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lb_lastUpdate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "updateDate") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Expire Date">
  <ItemTemplate><asp:Label ID="lb_expireDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "expireDate") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
      <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
      <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
      <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
      <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
      <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
      <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
      <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
      <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
      <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
  </asp:GridView>
```

Then I bind if on the page load event , like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            BindData();

        }
        protected void BindData()
        {
            string sqlConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["umbracoDbDSN"].ToString();
            string sqlSelect = "SELECT  cmsContentXml.nodeId,text, Max(updateDate) as UpdateDate,expireDate as ExpireDate from cmsContentXml,cmsDocument,cmsContent where cmsContent.nodeId=cmsContentXml.nodeId and cmsDocument.nodeId=cmsContent.nodeId  group by cmsContentXml.nodeId,text,expireDate";

            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectString);
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConnection);

            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            DataTable sqlDt = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt);

            GridViewFoundations.DataSource = sqlDt;
            GridViewFoundations.DataBind();

        }
```

And i have the following filter (for example by text)

```
protected void btn_filtro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["umbracoDbDSN"].ToString();
            string sqlSelect = "SELECT  cmsContentXml.nodeId,text, Max(updateDate) as UpdateDate,expireDate as ExpireDate from cmsContentXml,cmsDocument,cmsContent where cmsContent.nodeId=cmsContentXml.nodeId and cmsDocument.nodeId=cmsContent.nodeId  and text like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' group by cmsContentXml.nodeId,text,expireDate";

            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectString);
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConnection);



            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            DataTable sqlDt = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt);
            GridViewFoundations.DataSource = sqlDt;
            GridViewFoundations.DataBind();
        }
```

My problem is I can't change the index of the page and keep my filters on..

I have already tried

`GridViewFoundations.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex`

followed by

`gridviewFoundations.Databind()` or `BindData()`

but in the 1st case the gridview desapears and in the second it clears all the filters (obviously) .

So Can anyone help me changing the page of the grid with filters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case(`GridViewFoundations.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex followed by gridviewFoundations.Databind()` ) data disappears as you are not providing any datasource to rebing your grid after postback.

In second case(`BindData()`) you are binding grid without any filters, hence your filter is lost.

what you can do is create a new function

```
protected void BindFilteredData()
 {
            string sqlConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["umbracoDbDSN"].ToString();
            string sqlSelect = "SELECT  cmsContentXml.nodeId,text, Max(updateDate) as UpdateDate,expireDate as ExpireDate from cmsContentXml,cmsDocument,cmsContent where cmsContent.nodeId=cmsContentXml.nodeId and cmsDocument.nodeId=cmsContent.nodeId  and text like '%" + TextBox1.Text + "%' group by cmsContentXml.nodeId,text,expireDate";

            SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectString);
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlSelect, sqlConnection);



            SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
            DataTable sqlDt = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(sqlDt);
            GridViewFoundations.DataSource = sqlDt;
            GridViewFoundations.DataBind();
}
```

And on page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
     {
       BindData();
     }
      else
        BindFilteredData();

}
```

This will call BindData when your page loads first time and rest of the times it will call filtered data function.

Comment: I missed the obvious --' thanks man for sharing this easy solution ! thank you